# Getting a build error as "Error during page generation" while executing "mvn site" command

Tags: maven

I am gettting a build error as "Error during page generation" while executing "mvn site" command. Please let me know how to fix this issue if somebody has faced this error before.

I did not get this error when I removed the following plugin details from the POM.

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>

<version>2.7</version>

<configuration>

 <charset>UTF-8</charset>

 <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>

 <docfilessubdirs>true</docfilessubdirs>

 <links>

  <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/</link>

 </links>

 <source>1.5</source>

 <show>protected</show>

</configuration>
```

Following is the output I got.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error during page generation

Embedded error: Error rendering Maven report: Exit code: 1 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.java:189)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:958)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:328)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:322)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:299)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:145)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:385)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1002)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1192)
at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport$4.run(SecuritySupport.java:96)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(SecuritySupport.java:89)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findJarServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:250)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:223)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:128)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.LayoutParser.parseXML(LayoutParser.java:72)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.ClassBuilder.build(ClassBuilder.java:108)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(HtmlDoclet.java:155)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFiles(AbstractDoclet.java:164)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:106)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:64)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:42)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:269)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:143)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:340)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:41)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:31)
com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.LayoutParser.parseXML(LayoutParser.java:79)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.ClassBuilder.build(ClassBuilder.java:108)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(HtmlDoclet.java:155)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFiles(AbstractDoclet.java:164)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:106)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:64)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:42)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:269)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:143)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:340)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:41)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:31)
com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(HtmlDoclet.java:159)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFiles(AbstractDoclet.java:164)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:106)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:64)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:42)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:269)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:143)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:340)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:41)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:31)

Command line was:"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 minutes 43 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 16 15:09:01 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 67M/170M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Am getting the same error. Did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and resolved it by deleting the CLASSPATH environment variable. It looks like the classpath entries disrupt the maven-javadoc-plugin while performing the "jar" goal.

Comment: please try to elaborate(complete) your answer, it feels like unfinished. so your answer could be more understandable.